# Unity Firebase ARC error when building for iOS on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, automatic-ref-counting

I'm following the instructions found on the Firebase Unity Setup (iOS) page, and correctly generating the Xcode project from Unity. I can see that the podfile is correctly generated as well as the podfile.lock and Pods folder. But when I try to build it from Xcode, I get multiple errors on on GTMLogger.m:

- .../Pods/GoogleToolboxForMac/Foundation/GTMLogger.m:48:46: 'retain'
  is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
- .../Pods/GoogleToolboxForMac/Foundation/GTMLogger.m:48:46: ARC
  forbids explicit message send of 'retain'

I searched for this type of ARC errors but found nothing relating to firebase. I also tried installing the pods directly (with pod install), and modifying the podfile to generate the xcworkspace file, and opening this file on Xcode instead of the project file, but this gave different errors, like:

- diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
- diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
- error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock.

Which I also did a lot of research on but none of the solutions provided worked (cleaning the project, pod install, pod update, pod deintegrate, etc.)

Finally, based on [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/72), a firebase developer suggests that the xcworkspace is not really needed because the unity compilation injects all of the necessary dependencies directly in the generated xcodeproject.

So I'm back to the original setup, only using the xcode project generated as is by unity, unable to build because of the ARC errors listed above.

My current setup is:

- Unity 5.5.2f1
- XCode 8.3.2
- Firebase 3.0.1 (only using the Database sdk)
- Pod 1.2.1

Any ideas on how to proceed?